# assigning css property to parent, not to child

Tags: html, css, smartadmin

In my application, I am using bootstrap-tagsinput angular version (in smartadmin) which looks like this

[image: Bootstrap Tags Input]

code for bootstrap input tag:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group">
               <label>Type and enter to add an SMA</label>
               <input smartTags class="form-control tagsinput" value="{{tagsValues}}" data-role="tagsinput">
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I am using this in my dashboard inside widget as a widget toolbar in dropdown popover

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<div class="widget-toolbar">
            <div class="btn-group dropdown dropdown-large" dropdown>
                <a class="button-icon" title="SMA Filter" dropdownToggle aria-expanded="true">
                    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large filterDropwdownViewAlign" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
                    <div id="checkout-form" class="smart-form">
                        <header id="filterHeader">SMA</header>
                        <fieldset>
                            <form>
                                <div class="row form-group">
                                    <section class="col col-xs-12">
                                        <label class="form-control" style="border:0px;height:auto">
                                            <input id="smartTagInput" smartTags class="form-control tagsinput" value="{{smaValues}}" data-role="tagsinput">
                                        </label>
                                    </section>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have applied css properties to the popover

```
.filterFormAlign {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px  !important;

}
.filterFormAlignToggle{
    padding-left: 0px  !important;
}
.filterDropwdownViewAlign {
    margin: 35px 0 0;
    top: 3px;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .filterDropwdownViewAlign {
        min-width: 335px !important;
        left: -296px !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) and (min-width: 320px) {
    .filterDropwdownViewAlign {
        min-width: 310px !important;
        left: -255px !important;
    }
}
```

That bootstrap input tags element is not looking in this popover as I showed in the image above.

[image]

Maybe it is coming because of that `css` properties that is inherited by this input field also. So is there any way that those `css` properties will not be inherited by the `input` tag or element inside the `form`

Comment: Direct child css selector might help you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Comment: looks like you made it into a block level element

Comment: There is always something wrong if you have to use !important like this in your css ...

Comment: is there any way that whatever inside the <form> tag could not inherit the css properties I have applied to the popover

Comment: @jirigracik I tried before without !important but that changed nothing

Comment: @YashJain I am not saying it should immediately solve all your problems. I am saying there is something wrong with your code and design

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have an overwrite of css definition which is making `<input>` element display block instead of floated / inline.

I don't know if this is the solution but looking at the differences between the 2 cases I would suggest to close the `<label>` tag before the `<input>` element and not after input element, something like:

```
<label class="form-control" style="border:0px;height:auto">
</label>
<input id="smartTagInput" smartTags class="form-control tagsinput" value="{{smaValues}}" data-role="tagsinput">
```

And the whole snippet:

```
<div class="widget-toolbar">
            <div class="btn-group dropdown dropdown-large" dropdown>
                <a class="button-icon" title="SMA Filter" dropdownToggle aria-expanded="true">
                    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large filterDropwdownViewAlign" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
                    <div id="checkout-form" class="smart-form">
                        <header id="filterHeader">SMA</header>
                        <fieldset>
                            <form>
                                <div class="row form-group">
                                    <section class="col col-xs-12">
                                        <label class="form-control" style="border:0px;height:auto">
                                        </label>
                                            <input id="smartTagInput" smartTags class="form-control tagsinput" value="{{smaValues}}" data-role="tagsinput">

                                    </section>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```